# R regex / grep / grepl for letters followed by a dash and numbers

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to find the right grep notation to identify strings that have this pattern: Any number of letters followed by a dash (-) followed by any number of numbers.  For example `ABC-123` would be a fit while `123-ABC` or `A1-B2` would not.

I've tried `grepl('[[A:Za:z]]\\-[[0:9]]','ABC-123')` but am not getting the correct results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can change the range (`:`) to `-` and instead of `[[`.  In the pattern, we also specify the `^` and `$` for start and end of string respectively.  The `+` for letters and digits specify one or more ...

```
grepl("^[A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+$", str1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Or if we want to use `[[`,

```
grepl("^[[:alpha:]]+-\\d+$", str1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("ABC-123", "123-ABC", "A1-B2")
```